# django -- __init__() keywords must be strings

Tags: python, django, web-developer-toolbar

I was trying to run `python manage.py runserver` but I received the following errors. Do you know how I can fix it?

```
jalal@mona:/research/jalal/django/djcode/mysite$ python manage.py runserver

Validating models...

Unhandled exception in thread started by <bound method Command.inner_run of   <django.contrib.staticfiles.management.commands.runserver.Command object at 0x13f8ed0>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/jalal/.pythonbrew/pythons/Python-2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 92, in inner_run
```

`__init__() keywords must be strings`

How can this be fixed?

Thanks.

Comment: seems like there is an issue with your models. Could you give your models.py code ?

Comment: Are you running django 1.5 ?

Comment: what version of python are you using?

Comment: I am using django 1.5 with Python 2.6. I am trying to switch to Python 2.7 with pythonbrew like I used to do before but it says python2.7 is not installed. Also when I install python2.7 with sudo apt-get install and use which python it shows 2.6 @MichaelVayvala

Comment: here is the manage.py code in mysite folder however I didn't modify anything http://paste.ofcode.org/37LERTC2csTGBNyCJM42iLk @Pixou

Answer (score 4):

This is caused by a [known bug in Python 2.6](http://bugs.python.org/issue2646) in which unicode arguments are not handled correctly. Upgrading to Python 2.7 resolves the issue.

Comment: To be more specific, the minimum version of Python required for Django 1.5 is 2.6.5.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem with python 2.6.2 under opensuse linux. Then I tried django 1.5.5 unter Ubuntu 10.04 with python 2.6.5. This fixed the problem.

hansjh